# Obter o mês do campo datetime mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Colegas,

tenho uma tabela onde tem o campo datetime() do Mysql. Gostaria de pegar um determinado mês diretamente pela cláusula where. Pelo PHP sei como fazer, mas como eu faria diretamente pela consulta? Tentei dessa forma para pegar os registros de maio, mas não funcionou:

```
$mês = $_POST["MesBusca"]; // Vamos supor que seja mês de maio (05)
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE MONTH(DataAbertura) = MONTH(".$mes."); // Tentei também com o 5
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É isso aí o código mesmo. Talvez falte adicionar o ano do contrario ele vai pegar todos os registros de maio de todos os anos cadastrados no banco. Qual é o problema da consulta? não retorna nada? retorna a mais?

Comment: Olá rray. Não retorna nada. Editei o meu post com um print da coluna.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quer

Comment: Veja minha resposta a baixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem amigo não entendi muito bem o que você quer;
Mas vejamos se quer pegar todos os registros do mes de maio seria assim:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE MONTH(DataAbertura) = 5;
```

Onde 5 é o número do mês, o Month() já retorna uma valor inteiro não precisa converter o Month(5) como você fez;

Agora se quer pegar o mês de uma data especifica seria assim:

```
select MONTH(DataAbertura) from tabela
```

Comment: Perfeito GabrielLocalhost. Era exatamente isso. Retirar o MONTH(05) e colocar apenas o 5. Obrigado!